# Create custom tabs on github repo page

Tags: github

I recall I can create a custom tab on github repo page as shown in `documentation` below
[image]

It is set through `custom tabs` as shown below

[image]

But when I get to the github page, I cannot find the `Custom Tabs`. Did I miss anything, or is the `Custom Tabs` not available for personal Github repo, and just available on Organization Repo?

Answer (score 3):

It's currently only available on GitHub Enterprise Server and GitHub AE.